# Is there a way to cancel a promise?

Tags: node.js, promise

This code works well.

I have a list of available campaigns and another list of active users. For each user, I need to check which campaigns have been shown before. I would like to know if it is possible to dispense with my promise to write undefined in my return matrix.

Is there a way to cancel a promise?

In this case, if there is already a record in the redis node, the answer will be equal to one and I would like to cancel the promise to avoid **undefined return**.

How to fixed this?

```
VerificarCampanhaEnvio  : async function(user,campanhas){
     const CampanhaUsers       = [];
     let   sismember           = util.promisify(cliente_redis.sismember).bind(cliente_redis);
     return Promise.all(campanhas.map(async(campanha) =>{
          return sismember("subscription:"+user.id,campanha.id_campanha).then((response)=>{ 
              console.log('response',user.id,response,campanha.id_campanha);
              if(response  != 1){
                  data          = {};
                  data.user     = user;
                  data.campanha = campanha;
                  return data;
               }
          });
      })).then((response) => { 
          return response;
      });
},

FireMessage       : function(){
    Sucesso  = function(data,campanhas){
        if(campanhas.length > 0){
            self.GetInscritosAtivos(function(users){
                if(users     !== false){
                    var contador = 1;
                    users.map(async(user) =>{ 
                        var finalArray;
                        console.log('user.id',user.id);
                        finalArray   = await self.VerificarCampanhaEnvio(user,campanhas);     
                        var filtered = finalArray.filter(function(el){ return el != null; }); 
                        if(filtered.length > 0) self.EnviarMensagem(filtered[0]);    
                    });        
                }else console.log('fnpush:FireMessage','Nao existe subscricoes ativas');
            });
        }else console.log('fnpush:FireMessage','Nao existem campanhas de push disponiveis no 
         sistema.');
    }
    data                = {};
    data.zona           = {};
    data.zona.tipo      = 'push';
    data.sucesso        = Sucesso;
    data.falha          = fnCampanha.CampanhaInexistente;
    fnCampanha.GetCampanhas(data);    
}
```

Comment: But you discover that the answer is (or is not) equal to one asynchronously. Therefore, even if you could do so (and you can't) cancelling the promise would be the wrong thing to do. The promise's work is done when it delivers its `response`. If it were cancelled (before a response was delivered) you would never know the response.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to purge all `undefined` entries from `finalArray`, which is a wholly synchronous undertaking once the asynchronously derived `finalArray` has been delivered. The `var filtered = finalArray.filter(...)` expression appears to be correct, or at least along the right lines, so are you saying that `filtered` isn't what you expect?

Comment: The filter can be written more efficiently as `var filtered = finalArray.filter(el => !!el);` which will filter out anything falsy, but essentially what you appear to want.

Comment: So, is this approach I took to clearing undefined entries correct? I thought there was some way to invalidate the promise if the redis-server's response to sismember was different 1

Comment: I expected to eliminate the undefined return for FilterArray. Since I was unable to eliminate undefined returns, I decided to clean up by running filter = finalArray.filter (...). I figured there might be some way to resolve this, as my knowledge of asynchronous language is not advanced. Thank you

Comment: Yes it is totally the correct approach. Try my version of the filter expression. It should work.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much Roamer. I'll switch to your filter version

Comment: There may be more to do depending on how `fnCampanha.GetCampanhas()` uses the `Sucesso` function passed to it.